# my webpage project automatically take facebook info when someone give permission before

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

when i entered my webpage with my facebook account and give permissions i  am writing info i took on screen but when i close my webpage then open again it automatically take my info again. how can i prevent this. i want when someone login my website everytime he must use my button again to send info . my website is https://fahribilici.com/ and my code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<body>
<script>

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '--------------',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.2'
    });
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
      });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/tr_TR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2&appId=2194615170807288';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email', function(response) {
        document.getElementById("fname").value = response.first_name;
        document.getElementById("lname").value = response.last_name;    
        document.getElementById("email").value = response.email;  
     });
    } 
    else {
      document.getElementById("fname").value ="";
        document.getElementById("lname").value ="";    
        document.getElementById("email").value =""; 
    }
  }
</script>
<div>
        <form>
                First name:<br>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname"><br>
                Last name:<br>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lname"><br>
                Mail:<br>
                <input type="text" name="mail" id="email"><br>
              </form>

</div>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" data-use-continue-as="true" scope="public_profile,email" auth_type="rerequest" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></div>

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" auth_type="rerequest" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don´t use FB.getLoginStatus then

Comment: but how can i check people logged or not ? also i tried and didnt work

Comment: then use FB.getLoginStatus and FB.login instead, whenever you want to

Comment: okay its working my bad thanks